# CSS Hover text/tooltip broken on mobile

Tags: css, mobile

I've just finished adding some tooltips to my website. I created them by pretty much copy+pasting the code from the tutorial below.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Everything works great on PC, but on mobile (I'm on Android, if it matters) it's completely broken. It functions as if the CSS classes weren't there at all i.e. the text that should be hidden as part of the tooltip is instead just printed on the page.

Anyone know what I might have done wrong?

Working tooltip

[image: Tooltip working]

Not working tooltip
[image: Broken]

Comment: It would not work on mobile because you can't "hover" the way you would on desktop. It would have to be on "active".

"Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example."

Comment: @rawnewdlz I don't want it to hover, I want it to not appear. As for the code, if I knew the minimum code required to make it happen, I probably would already know how to fix it. These tooltips are being added to a preexisting website. I'm here because I'm looking for advice on where to look for problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tooltip should not appear on mobile, then it's possible to hide it using media-queries. The below example is done based on the HTML & CSS from the w3school example you shared. Do note, without an example of your working HTML & CSS it's possible something else is overriding the tooltip and forcing it to appear. In that case you would have to inspect it in mobile view with a browser's dev toolkit to see what it could be.

```
@media only screen and (min-width:40em) {
  .tooltip .tooltiptext { display:none;}
}
```

Comment: No dice. Did pretty much the opposite of what I want. The mobile site is still broken but the tooltips no longer show up on desktop. Thanks for your help anyway. I guess I'll spend some time tearing down and rebuilding the CSS file until I can figure out where it's breaking.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't include the complete media query for small screens. Can you please try again?

Comment: I had to use max-width:400px, but otherwise it worked. Thanks!